# X-Ray acting weird after tweaking MatCap

Tags: modeling

I was trying to set a new MatCap tweaking colors and stuff, but after this I'm unable to use X-ray properly.
In detail, the object is visible only if I'm not looking from the front. In that case, it becomes fully transparent. I also tried changing the x-ray opacity, but if it's set to 1.00 is fully opaque, while setting only on .95 gives the result in the images.

Thanks!

[image: Side view]

[image: Front view]